# Add tikz styled Summary heading

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, memoir

As per MWE, I currently use two kinds of section header bars: a rounded grey bar for ordinary unnumbered sections ('osections' in MWE) and a 'Topic N', for numbered sections (where N=section number)

I want to add another 'type' of heading bar, i.e. 'Summary', using a tikz node:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

%   MWE, as per http://glurl.co/dFH

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\setsecnumdepth{section}
\maxsecnumdepth{section}

\usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}

\definecolor{topic}{rgb}{.125,.125,.500}    % 
\definecolor{info}{rgb}{.125,.125,.500} % 

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}     
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\makeatletter
\let\currentsectiontitle\relax      

\newcommand\titlebar@{%sections
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3.15cm] {
    \fill [black!15] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [fill=black!15!white,
        anchor= base east,
    rounded rectangle,
    minimum height=3.5ex] at (2.8cm,0.13) {};
    \node [fill=black!100!white,    anchor= base east,  rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.75ex] at (14cm,0.05) {
        \color{white}{Topic \thesection}};
}}
\newcommand\titlebar@@{%osections
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3.15cm] {
    \fill [black!15] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.6cm,2.5ex);
    \node [fill=black!15!white, anchor= base east,  rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (2.8cm,0.13) {};
    \node [fill=black!15!white, anchor= base east,  rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (13.5cm,0.13) {};
}}
\newcommand\stitlebar@@{%ssections
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3.15cm] {
    \fill [black!15] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.6cm,2.5ex);
    \node [fill=black!15!white, anchor= base east,  rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (2.8cm,0.13) {};
    \node [fill=black!100!white,    anchor= base east,  rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (14.0cm,0.03) {
    \color{white}{Summary}};
}}
\newcommand\titlebar{\@ifstar\titlebar@@\titlebar@}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\titlebar}
    {0.1cm}{\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\newcommand{\osection}[1]{\section*{\titlebar*#1}}

\newcommand\summary{\stitlebar@@}
\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{\section*{\summary#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\pagestyle{empty}   

\osection{Ordinary Section Header}
This is for ordinary sections.  

\section{Topical Section Header}
This is for topical sections

\ssection{Summary Section Header}
I'd like to replace this topical header with a similar tikz bar which has 'Summary' in the black node

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through trial and error, I have resolved this question, as follows.

1. Defined a new command, stitlebar@@, based on titlebar@@

   \newcommand\stitlebar@@{%ssections
   \tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3.15cm] {
       \fill [black!15] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.6cm,2.5ex);
       \node [fill=black!15!white, anchor= base east,  rounded rectangle,
           minimum height=3.5ex] at (2.8cm,0.13) {};
       \node [fill=black!100!white,    anchor= base east,  rounded rectangle,
           minimum height=3.5ex] at (14.0cm,0.03) {
       \color{white}{Summary}};
   }}
2. Defined two new commands, summary and ssection:

   \newcommand\summary{\stitlebar@@}
   \newcommand{\ssection}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1PQE.png){\section*{\summary#1}}
3. Added ssection to MWE (which is now edited to include this edition)
4. Result:

[image]